# Coroutine is causing uneven spacing between objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a `Coroutine`, and I have tried using `WaitForSecondsRealtime` and `WaitForSeconds`. When I run the `Coroutine`, the delay is the same for a few iterations, but then there is a gap where the delay is a little longer, then it goes back, then there is a delay again.

Here is an image of what is happening, as you can see there are a few gaps between circles, and I would like the gaps to be a bit more constant.

[image: Gap]

Here is the `Coroutine` that I am using for this:

```
public float shootDelay = 0.03f;

IEnumerator Shoot(Vector3 direction) {
    direction.z = 0f;
    foreach (GameObject ball in balls) {
        float speed = ball.GetComponent<Ball>().speed;
        ball.GetComponent<Ball>().rb.velocity = direction.normalized * speed;
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(shootDelay);
    }
}
```

Comment: This hurts my eyes. *I* would like the gaps between circles to be exactly the same!

Comment: Unless you modified the `Time.timeScale` variable, there is no need to use `WaitForSecondsRealtime()`. The error you are witnessing is caused by Unity not waiting exactly the `shootDelay`, but rather the _frame after shootDelay is completed_.

Comment: I am curious. What happens if you use 0.02f as a shoot delay instead? Same result? how about 0.3f or 0.5f?

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell from your tiny bit of code exactly what your question is. A good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help a lot (perhaps minus the standard Unity3d boilerplate…there's an art to providing just the right amount of code for a Unity3d question).

But is *seems* like you are trying to implement a delay between "balls" being "shot" from something. As such, you want for each ball to be initialized at precise intervals. They are not, which results in irregular intervals.

Unfortunately, I don't think you can count on the `WaitForSecondsRealtime()` (or `WaitForSeconds()`, for that matter…which is probably a better choice here, as it would automatically adjust if you change the game simulation speed). [These functions](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html) have significant sources of imprecision that you will need to take into account, particularly that the time that's waited is counted only after the current frame is entirely complete and your coroutine is only resumed at the first frame after the specified time has elapsed.

One way to take into account this imprecision is by using the [`Time.time`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-time.html) value to track how much simulation time has actually passed since you started firing the bullets. Initialize a variable in the coroutine just before the loop, to the current value. Then when you are setting the `velocity` of the bullet object, also set its `position` based on the velocity and the difference between the current time value and that bullet's intended time value. Then wait for a period of time not the exact interval you want, but an interval that represents the difference between the current time and the next bullet time.

Without a good MCVE it's not practical for me to try to test this (i.e., I haven't), but something like this should work:

```
IEnumerator Shoot(Vector3 direction) {
    direction.z = 0f;
    float nextBulletTime = Time.time;
    foreach (GameObject ball in balls) {
        Ball ballComponent = ball.GetComponent<Ball>();
        float speed = ballComponent.speed;
        Rigidbody rb = ballComponent.rb;

        rb.velocity = direction.normalized * speed;
        rb.position += rb.velocity * (Time.time - nextBulletTime);

        nextBulletTime += shootDelay;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(nextBulletTime - Time.time);
    }
}
```